# Apple Mach-O Librarian Error on Mac

Tags: ios, xcode6.1

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0LdQn.jpg)I am very new on iOS application. I am try to run the project from my PC and I got the following error. It's not working. [image]

Is it because of miss matching Xcode version or something? Please tell me detail explanation. Thanks you..

[image]
This is the result from libx264.a.

Comment: Where did that `libx264.a` come from?

Comment: it in my project. it put that file to Link binary with libraries(at build phases). is it the problem?

Comment: Yes; however I don't quite understand the error messages.  It looks like there are directories (ending with `.o`) in there.  However that should not be possible.  You need to show what it contains; so go to the command line, find the `.a` file and do `xcrun ar t libx264.a` and update your question with the output.

Comment: @ Droppy I just update the question. is it the result that you want?

Comment: Yeah they look like directories.  It looks corrupt and cannot be used.

Comment: so what should it be?

Comment: Should I need to download new one? can I edit the existing one?

Comment: They should be object files.  If you didn't create the library then you need to contact the person that did for a fixed version of it.

Comment: okay thanks you Droppy :) you help me a lot